# Remove pixels with Python, cv2

Tags: python, seam, pixel

I'm trying to implement Seam Carving Method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving). Now I have the seams, which are displaed on the picture, but I don't know how to remove these seams efficiently. Do you know how to do this?

[example seams](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/BroadwayTowerSeamCarvingD.png)